# Spring Security RememberMe success handler or url filtering

Tags: security, spring, remember-me

I am using Spring Security with a login page and a remember-me filter. The remember-me filtering can happen on any page of the application.

But I want the same behaviour both when the user is authenticated from login page and from the cookie:

- I want to set some user information in session
- I want to redirect the user to the home page (always-use-default-target="true")

I have seen that the success-handler for the remember-me tag is supported by Spring Security since the 3.1.0 (https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1603).

Another solution for me would be to restrict the URL for the remember-me filter, like the intercept-url. I would allow the remember-me filtering only on the default or home page URL.

Is there a standard way to restrict the URL for the remember-me filter or to redirect the user after cookie authentication before the version 3.1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure - subclass RememberMeAuthenticationFilter and override `doFilter()`.  If the request is for the home page call `super.doFilter()`, otherwise call `chain.doFilter(`).

Comment: thanks, it means I have to hard-code or define with custom properties the URLs that must be intercepted by the filter. It is ok, but I wondered if there was a kind of intercept-url.

Comment: In Spring 3.0 all the filters apply to all the intercept-urls.  In 3.1 you can have different filters applying to different urls.